# Better implementation of collecting child instances of given class

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code which provides the logic of this solution, but I'm aware that collecting an instance from within the constructor is dangerous.

Does anyone know a better solution?

The goal is to collect all instances that are extending this class. My preferred solution is the one the uses as little resources as possible (libraries, cpu, ram) although I know that there will always be a tradeoff.

I've tried something with reflection, annotation, classpath search but non of them seemed to be the silver bullet.

```
class Parent{
    private companion object{
        var childs = arrayListOf<Parent>()
    }

    constructor(){
        childs.add(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to collect all instances you should anyway somehow get those instances upon their creation (will it be the constructor or factory method, if any). Also you should somehow store them (maybe `LinkedList` is a better choice). So your approach seems reasonable.

But remember that within this approach these instances will be linked from a `static` place, which means that they wouldn't be garbage collected. If you don't want that, you could store them using a `WeakReference` (more precisely a collection of `WeakReference<Parent>`'s).